# Unable to update sys.columns - any other approach?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, system-tables

I just found out, that since I created my DB on a different server that had a different collation, then immigrated to a new server with new collation, now I keep on having trouble, and I decided to change all the values of the old collation.

So I tried to execute this query:

```
sp_configure "Allow Updates", 1
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO

UPDATE sys.columns SET collation_name = 
    'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS' WHERE collation_name = 'Hebrew_CI_AS'
GO

sp_configure "Allow Updates", 0
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

But here is the output of the query:

```
Configuration option 'allow updates' changed from 0 to 1. 
    Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.

Msg 259, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.

Configuration option 'allow updates' changed from 1 to 0. 
    Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
```

**UPDATE**
According to the answers bellow, I am just looking for an automated way to perform the action.

Comment: SYS tables are read-only -- you need to get a list, and update the collation against the actual table/column

Comment: @OMG Ponies, OK, so bottom line, is there an automated way to do it, as I am talking about a large amount of columns in various tables. I think I'll create a console application that generates the SQL script according to the values from sys.columns and sys.tables, if you have any other shorter ways, please lemme know.

Comment: Can you describe - which problems?  

Note that you probably have dependencies on columns with collation in question, like constraints, indexes, etc   
You will not be able to change collation without dropping them first. 

I doubt that you should fo it at all in this way as well as you correctly understood why and what to do.  

For example, why are you doing this on target (production?) database? Why have had this collation in first place? Why don't you change collation on your development server?  How are you going to maintain it?

Comment: vg8, look at my answer, there was indeed errors, but i had to edit 10 columns manually with the designer, all the other thousands were automated! still something!

Comment: I posted subquestion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020870/what-issues-to-anticipate-having-different-collations-between-development-and-pro

Comment: One more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034114/how-to-script-non-default-collation-and-skip-explicit-scripting-for-default-colla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query is generates a script that will swap all `Hebrew_CI_AS` collated columns to `Latin1_General_CI_AS` collation:

```
DECLARE @Script varchar(MAX)
SET @Script = CAST((
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE [' + Tables.Name + '] ALTER COLUMN [' + 
  [Columns].Name + '] ' + Types.Name + '(' + 
  CAST([Columns].max_length AS varchar) + ') COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS ' + 
  CASE WHEN [Columns].is_nullable = 0 THEN 'NOT ' ELSE '' END + 'NULL '
FROM sys.tables Tables INNER JOIN sys.all_columns [Columns]
  ON [Tables].[object_id] = [Columns].[object_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.types Types ON [Columns].system_type_id = Types.system_type_id
WHERE [Columns].collation_name = 'Hebrew_CI_AS'
FOR XML PATH('')
) AS varchar(MAX))

PRINT @Script
EXEC(@Script)
```

**NOTE:** For columns that are indexed/constrained you'll need to edit manually, but that's also something since when executing the above query the error-result (for a constraint etc.) contains the table & column name, you must admit it's still better than do everything manually.

Comment: May I mark this post as answer? because the questioner will not gain reputation on marking your own answer

Answer (score 4):

You need to issue ALTER TABLE commands in order to change the collations of the specific columns.

e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable 
ALTER COLUMN ColA VARCHAR(10) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL
```

Check out [this MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190920.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `alter table` to change the collation for each column.

The only way to change a database collation is to drop and recreate the database.